# why is the correct answer "the"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, sentence-structure, american-english, conjunctions

Gilbert Stuart is considered by most art critics ……………. greatest portrait painter north American colonels

1-that he was

2-as he was

3- who was the

4- the

why is the answer "4" not "3" or"1","2"?

Answer (score 1):

Because none of the others result in a grammatical sentence.

> Gilbert Stuart is considered by most art critics that he was greatest portrait painter North America contains.

"that he was greatest" does not work, neither does "is considered ... that"

> Gilbert Stuart is considered by most art critics as he was greatest portrait painter North America contains.

This has much the same problems: "as he was greatest' simply cannot work.

> Gilbert Stuart is considered by most art critics who  was the greatest portrait painter North America contains.

"is considered ... who" does not work

> Gilbert Stuart is considered by most art critics [to be] the greatest portrait painter North America contains.

everything works.

Comment: "is considered ... who" does not work ,can you elaborate why ??